# I uploaded image to the server, but failed to bring images

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am using mean stack from https://github.com/linnovate/mean

Problem : I could not able to get image from the node server which is saved in /mean/server/images folder.

When I try to access a static image from the browser=>localhost:4040/images
it gives me 401 Unauthorized error.

I don't know why it does not work.
Could you please able to give me an advice?

I added this line in mean/server/config/config,js

```
-mean
-----server
--------- config
-------------config.js
-------- controllers
-------- data
-------- images <---I saved images here using "multer "package
```

app.use('images', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/../images')))

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it really help you 
but you can try this

`app.use('/images', express.static('./../images'))`

instead of

`app.use('images', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/../images')))`